# What will happen if I close the terminal in the middle of an upgrading process?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Accidentally, I closed the terminal in the middle of the process of

```
sudo apt-get upgrade firefox
```

Is this dangerous? If any one has this experience then please share your problems and errors which you have got.

Comment: You interrupted the upgrade. It depends on your luck how many problems you will get.

Comment: If your computer is setup to suspend or close, then it's dangerous! But don't do that you might regret it...

Comment: Retry the upgrade. You may need to `sudo rm` a lock file, first. Tell us what errors you get.

Comment: still now i didn't get any error.

Comment: I've updated my question.